# Determine attached managed disks of a VM

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I want to determine the managed disk IDs of all data disks that are attached to a particular VM. The data sources "azurerm_managed_disk" and "azurerm_virtual_machine" are of no great help, they do not provide information about the relationship between the VM and its disks.

In PowerShell, you have .StorageProfile subspace in the VM object which gives you that information, but how do I determine this relation in Terraform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, there exactly is no data resource you can directly get the managed disk that attached to the special VM. But you can get the disks information in PowerShell script as you think. And then execute the script in the Terraform through [External Data Source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html). So that you can get the disks information in Terraform indirectly. The Terraform code like below:

```
data "external" "powershell_test" {
  program = ["Powershell.exe", "./vmDisk.ps1"]
}

output "value" {
  value = "${data.external.powershell_test.result}"
}
```